# uWSGI + Flask Request Data performance issue

Tags: python, json, performance, flask, uwsgi

I have some performance issues when configuring our Flask app to run within uWSGI. Previously it was running in a detached tmux session using:

```
python application.py run
```

Now I have reconfigured it to run inside uWSGI using the following service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Flask App
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=30
User=nginx
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/flaskapp
ExecStart=/bin/bash /var/www/flaskapp/run.sh
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
```

And the following run script (as we are running Python 3.8 on CentOS 7 which is not available by default):

```
source scl_source enable devtoolset-9 rh-python38
source venv/bin/activate
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

And the following INI file:

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
thunder-lock = true
http-socket = 0.0.0.0:5000
wsgi-file = application.py
virtualenv = /var/www/flaskapp/venv/
module = application:app
processes = 4
threads = 2
gid = nginx
uid = nginx
chmod-socket = 664
max-requests = 5000
harakiri = 60
socket = %dapp.sock
lazy-apps = true
vacuum = true
enable-threads = true
buffer-size = 32768
```

Everything is working and when testing with **ab** I do have way more requests per second served, so basically everything is fine. But it seems like there is a small delay (I guess something between 300 and 1000 ms) on every requests when parsing arguments from the request body (we pinned that down using debug logs) here:

```
from flask_restful import request
...
args['data'] = request.get_json().get('data')
```

Is anybody aware of something behaving differently when running inside uWSGI or running from shell regarding that request JSON parse? Like e.g. a 500 ms timeout trying to open stdin (which should be mapped to /dev/null as far as i know) or something? Or maybe there is some configuration error?

Edit:
Using uWSGI 2.0.19.1 + Python 3.8.6

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody is looking for the same problem, I found the solution.

As most guides recommend to use nginx on top of uWSGI I tried that and for some reason the performance issue is gone after an additional layer is added.

nginx config:

```
    location / {
        root /your/path/to/app;
        uwsgi_pass unix:////your/path/to/app/app.sock;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
```

uWSGI INI:

```
[uwsgi]
...
chmod-socket = 664
socket = %dapp.sock
buffer-size = 32768
...
```